# Can I tell loader to ignore some sections when loading an ELF file?

Tags: c++, unix, ld, elf, loader

Currently I'm doing an experiment on implement C++20 module system.
Here's how I do this: I serialized the AST to a an global array variable, and make this variable locate to a custom section, let's say the section is named "_ast".

Since this "_ast" section is useless in run time, can I tell the loader to ignore this section? That is, do not load this section to memory, or delete this after loading?

Comment: Which Compiler & Linker are you using? The GNU linker "ld" supports a "NOLOAD" [attribute](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.33.1/ld/Output-Section-Type.html#Output-Section-Type) in the linker script, which tells the loader to not load that section.

Comment: GNU ld, actually.